# How to collect input value with different names?

Tags: php, html, forms

I have 3 dropdown selection input and one textarea input. I think it's invalid to make all names the same, so, each input has a different name though I can make them all start with the same string.
On the form submit, I want to join all the input value into one. 
I can only think of making a hidden input to collect the values, but I don't know how to code it. Please help!

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <select id="input-first_dropdown" name="property-first_dropdown">
                <option>Option 1</option>
                <option>Option 2</option>
                <option>Option 3</option>
        </select>
    </li>
    <li>
        <select id="input-second_dropdown" name="property-second_dropdown">
                <option>Option 1</option>
                <option>Option 2</option>
                <option>Option 3</option>
        </select>
    </li>
    <li>
        <textarea id="input-textarea" name="property-textarea">test</textarea>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Why vote down the question without a comment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>
    <select id="input-first_dropdown" name="property[]">
        <option>Option 1</option>
        <option>Option 2</option>
        <option>Option 3</option>
    </select>
    </li>
    <li>
    <select id="input-second_dropdown" name="property[]">
        <option>Option 1</option>
        <option>Option 2</option>
        <option>Option 3</option>
    </select>
    </li>
    <li>
    <textarea id="input-textarea" name="property[]">test</textarea>
    </li>
</ul>
```

try `print_r($_POST['property'])` in your form processor

Comment: Thanks, this works! I've been bothered by this for a long time, today finally got it done.

Answer (score 1):

You can have the same `name` attribute value for different input fields (but not the same `id` value). The data will then be submitted so that there are several name=value pairs with the same name. Whether and how you can handle that server-side is a different matter. Normally it is easier to use different names. In server-side processing, you can combine the data as desired.

You cannot reliably combine input fields “on the form submit,” i.e. client-side. Although it would be easy to do that in JavaScript, it would have no point, since you should not rely on JavaScript being enabled in the browser.